# FoundationKit on gcc/Linux

Tags: objective-c, foundationkit

I am trying to test Objective-C on Linux (Ubuntu 10.04), mainly to decide if it's worth it to get a Mac and XCode. I have to like a language before I seriously consider programming in it (even more so when I have to pay a lot for it)

I am using gcc (with gobjc++). But this of course does not include the Foundation Kit and the rest of the Cocoa API (not overly concerned about this one).

Short of [GNUStep](http://www.gnustep.org/), what is the best way for me to get into Obj-C programming in Linux or Windows? I want to get at least class in the FoundationKit.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- [GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org/), which is focused on Linux
- [Cocotron](http://www.cocotron.org/), which is focused on Windows

Those are the only freely available implementations of Foundation that I'm aware of.

Honestly, the language is hardly ever used outside of the Apple ecosystem, so you're not going to get a first-class experience here. Not knocking those groups' efforts, but if you're looking for something comparable to what you get on OS X, it just isn't there.